# Switch case with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

Am I writing the correct switch case with conditions?

```js
var cnt = $("#div1 p").length;
alert(cnt);

switch (cnt) {
  case (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20):
    alert('10');
    break;
  case (cnt >= 21 && cnt <= 30):
    alert('21');
    break;
  case (cnt >= 31 && cnt <= 40):
    alert('31');
    break;
  default:
    alert('>41');
}
```

For some reason, the alert does not occur when the conditions are matched!

Comment: have you heard about if...elseif...else statement?

Comment: IMO the correct answer to this question received the least up vote. See Fabien Ménager's answer. This should be the right one. Writing this kind of code using switch is more readable than using if else statement. I personally use this one in situations like this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should not use `switch` for this scenario.  This is the proper approach:

```
var cnt = $("#div1 p").length;

alert(cnt);

if (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20)
{
   alert('10');
}
else if (cnt >= 21 && cnt <= 30)
{
   alert('21');
}
else if (cnt >= 31 && cnt <= 40)
{
   alert('31');
}
else 
{
   alert('>41');
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using switch in this scenario. I prefer switch over if else for this.

Comment: "You should not use switch for this scenario"

**Why?**

Answer (score 91):

A switch works by comparing what is in `switch()` to every `case`.

```
switch (cnt) {
    case 1: ....
    case 2: ....
    case 3: ....
}
```

works like:

```
if (cnt === 1) ...
if (cnt === 2) ...
if (cnt === 3) ...
```

Therefore, you can't have any logic in the case statements.

```
switch (cnt) {
    case (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20): ...
}
```

works like

```
if (cnt === (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20)) ...
```

and that's just nonsense. :)

Use `if () { } else if () { } else { }` instead.

Comment: cant agree more with your ````nonsense```` part

Answer (score 27):

This should work with this :

```
var cnt = $("#div1 p").length;

            switch (true) {
                case (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20):
                    alert('10');
                    break;
                case (cnt >= 21 && cnt <= 30):
                   alert('21');
                    break;
                case (cnt >= 31 && cnt <= 40):
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('>41');
            }
```

Comment: I didn't say this is a good code ;) And switch permits this. This is like when you write `if ( 2 == myVar) `

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that switch statement and it is exactly as intended. Translated, you're asking "Give me the "true" statement" and perform this code for it.

I personally like the switch statement better than a bunch of if..else if.. statements.

Comment: You'd better replace >=21 with >20 and so on.

Answer (score 10):

Something I came upon while trying to work a spinner was to allow for flexibility within the script without the use of a ton of **if** statements.

Since this is a simpler solution than iterating through an array to check for a single instance of a class present it keeps the script cleaner. Any suggestions for cleaning the code further are welcome.

```
$('.next').click(function(){
        var imageToSlide = $('#imageSprite'); // Get id of image

        switch(true) {
            case (imageToSlide.hasClass('pos1')):
                imageToSlide.removeClass('pos1').addClass('pos2');
                break;
            case (imageToSlide.hasClass('pos2')):
                imageToSlide.removeClass('pos2').addClass('pos3');
                break;
            case (imageToSlide.hasClass('pos3')):
                imageToSlide.removeClass('pos3').addClass('pos4');
                break;
            case (imageToSlide.hasClass('pos4')):
                imageToSlide.removeClass('pos4').addClass('pos1');
        }
    }); `
```

Answer (score 9):

What you are doing is to look for (0) or (1) results.

(cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20) returns either true or false.

--edit--
**you can't use case with boolean (logic) experessions. The statement cnt >= 10 returns zero for false or one for true. Hence, it will we case(1) or case(0) which will never match to the length.**
--edit--

Comment: Andy you probably have a point here that I cld not follow..mind rewording that? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use case with boolean (logic) experessions. The statement cnt >= 10 returns zero for false or one for true. Hence, it will we case(1) or case(0) which will never match to the length.

Answer (score 5):

```
function date_conversion(start_date){
    var formattedDate = new Date(start_date);
    var d = formattedDate.getDate();
    var m =  formattedDate.getMonth();
    var month;
    m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
    switch (m) {
        case 1: {
            month="Jan";
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            month="Feb";
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            month="Mar";
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            month="Apr";
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            month="May";
            break;
        }
        case 6: {
            month="Jun";
            break;
        }
        case 7: {
            month="Jul";
            break;
        }
        case 8: {
            month="Aug";
            break;
        }
        case 9: {
            month="Sep";
            break;
        }
        case 10: {
            month="Oct";
            break;
        }
        case 11: {
            month="Nov";
            break;
        }
        case 12: {
            month="Dec";
            break;
        }
    }
    var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
    var now_date=d + "-" + month + "-" + y;
    return now_date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch case is every help full instead of if else statement :

```
     switch ($("[id*=btnSave]").val()) {
        case 'Search':
            saveFlight();
            break;
        case 'Update':
            break;
        case 'Delete':
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is late but in case you  or someone else still want to you use a switch or simply have a better understanding of how the switch statement works.

What was wrong is that your switch expression should match in strict comparison one of your case expression. If there is no match it will look for a default.  You can still use your expression in your case with the && operator that makes Short-circuit evaluation.

Ok you already know all that. For matching the strict comparison you should add at the end of all your case expression && cnt.

Like follow:

```
switch(mySwitchExpression)
case customEpression && mySwitchExpression: StatementList
.
.
.
default:StatementList
```

```js
var cnt = $("#div1 p").length;
alert(cnt);
switch (cnt) {
case (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20 && cnt):
    alert('10');
    break;
case (cnt >= 21 && cnt <= 30 && cnt):
    alert('21');
    break;
case (cnt >= 31 && cnt <= 40 && cnt):
    alert('31');
    break;
default:
    alert('>41');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
<p> p1</p>
<p> p2</p>
<p> p3</p>
<p> p3</p>
<p> p4</p>
<p> p5</p>
<p> p6</p>
<p> p7</p>
<p> p8</p>
<p> p9</p>
<p> p10</p>
<p> p11</p>
<p> p12</p>
</div>
```