# Why does my jquery work on jsFiddle but not on my localHost?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jsfiddle

The code that works on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NTadX/

My jquery code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/mystyle.css" />

<style>
    $(function(){
$("input[value='WN']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
        $("#divid").append("<div>WN: Weekly Number. The number of consecutive weeks you want to book the room</div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
$("input[value='DN']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
         $("#divid").append("<div>DN: Day Number. The number of consecutive days you want to book the room</div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
$("input[value='DD']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
         $("#divid").append("<div>DD: Day date. The date till which you want to book the room for consecutive days </div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
$("input[value='WD']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
         $("#divid").append("<div>WD: Weekly date. The date till which you want to book the room for consecutve weeks</div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
 });
</style>
```

I have checked around and the above code only starts when the document is fully loaded... i really don't know why it isn't working. I'm running this on google app engine. Thanks

Comment: Your code is in a style tag, for one.

Comment: Do you see any error in your Console?Is it problematic in Chrome only or in other browsers as well on Localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("input[value='WN']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
        $("#divid").append("<div>WN: Weekly Number. The number of consecutive weeks you want to book the room</div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
$("input[value='DN']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
         $("#divid").append("<div>DN: Day Number. The number of consecutive days you want to book the room</div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
$("input[value='DD']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
         $("#divid").append("<div>DD: Day date. The date till which you want to book the room for consecutive days </div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
$("input[value='WD']").hover(
    function() { 
        $('#divid').empty();
         $("#divid").append("<div>WD: Weekly date. The date till which you want to book the room for consecutve weeks</div>"); 
        $("#divid").toggle();
    }
);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `toogle()` is causing problem for you.
Here a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk5n/6/)

Switch Case Would have been better

[Switch case in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696436/switch-case-in-jquery)

More refined version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x5xRG/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.selectionItems").live('hover', function() {

        optSelected = $(this).val();
        toUpdate = $("#divid");

    switch (optSelected) {
                    case ('WN'):
                        toUpdate.html("<div>WN: Weekly Number. The number of consecutive weeks you want to book the room</div>"); 
                        break;
                    case ('DN'):
                        toUpdate.html("<div>DN: Day Number. The number of consecutive days you want to book the room</div>"); 
                        break;
                    case ('DD'):
                       toUpdate.html("<div>DD: Day date. The date till which you want to book the room for consecutive days </div>"); 
                        break;
                    case ('WD'):
                       toUpdate.html("<div>WD: Weekly date. The date till which you want to book the room for consecutve weeks</div>"); 
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('No Selection');
                }
            }
      );


    $('input.selectionItems').live('mouseleave', function(){
        $("#divid").empty();
    });
});​
```