# Replace multiple if statements when checking for multiple integer ranges

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I would like to simplify this code by removing all those `if statements` with, if it's possible off course, a single function and/or everything that could be used to remove those if recurrencies.

I need to check multiple integer ranges and according to the user score I need to set two variables.

This is my code:

```
if (userScore <= 40)
{
    object.setMinValue(0);
    object.setMaxValue(40);
}

if (userScore > 40 && userScore <= 65)
{
    object.setMinValue(41);
    object.setMaxValue(65);
}

if (userScore > 65 && userScore <= 85)
{
    object.setMinValue(66);
    object.setMaxValue(85);
}

if (userScore > 85 && userScore <= 95)
{
    object.setMinValue(86);
    object.setMaxValue(95);
}

if (userScore > 95 && userScore <= 100)
{
    object.setMinValue(96);
    object.setMaxValue(100);
}
```

I think that a `switch` statement could be used since there are many `if statements` that checks for the same variable, but is there a simpler and more effective [expecially for performance] solution?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696436/switch-case-in-jquery

Comment: switch statement can't be used here, because you have ranges, not fixed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not very good to use `object` for a variable name in javascript. I'm using 'o' instead.
As i can figure out from your code, the values in code blocks can be derived from conditional statements:

```
var scoreLimits = [0,40,65,85,95,100];

for(var i = 1; i < scoreLimits.length; i++)
{
    var limit = scoreLimits[i];
    if ( userScore <= limit )
    {
        o.setMinValue(scoreLimits[i-1]);
        o.setMaxValue(limit);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xsasjs6t/

And if you want it to run really fast, you can precompute a map for the entire range of possible userScore values and use it later:

```
var mapper = {};
for(var i = 0; i < scoreLimits.length - 1; i++)
{
    var limits = { minValue : scoreLimits[i], maxValue : scoreLimits[i+1] };
    for (var j = scoreLimits[i] + 1; j <= scoreLimits[i + 1]; j++)
    {
        mapper[j] = limits;
    }
}
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8cqwp4fz/

Comment: Hello George, in my original code i didn't use "object" but an other variable name but whn posting the question I replaced it with that. Thanks for your answer :-)