# Using mathematics in a switch statement case?

Tags: javascript

So I've slowly been learning javascript on Code Academy and I'm curious if I can use a mathematical equation as an indicator for my case in a switch? I built this little if/else loop but wanted to know if I could have the same process under a switch statement.

If/Else loop

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
        console.log('FizzBuzz');
    }
    else if (i % 3 === 0){
        console.log('Fizz');
    } 
    else if (i % 5 === 0){
        console.log('Buzz');
    } 
    else {
    console.log(i);
    }
}
```

And this is the switch statement I crafted that I thought would work.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    switch (
    case (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0):
        console.log('FizzBuzz')
        break;
    case (i % 3 === 0):
        console.log('Fizz')
        break;
    case (i % 5 === 0):
        console.log('Buzz')
        break;
    default:
    console.log(i);
  )
}
```

Comment: The loop surpasses the switch in this case because you're checking mutiple values. Go back to using the loop and read some more on use-cases for switch.

Comment: Specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2697105/476

Comment: dont use brackets in swicth statement remove those

Comment: You cant have logic in switch statements case

Comment: Yep that's what i meant lol