# Multiple value returned in JS/How to access an array of returned value from outside the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript.How to access an array of returned value from outside the function

```js
var myDob=prompt('Enter the year of birth')

function calcualteMyAge(myDob)
{
    var d =new Date();
    
    var age=(d.getFullYear())-myDob;
    
    
   function calculateRange(age)
    {
        
                   switch(true)
                   {    
                       case  (age>=1 && age<= 12):
                               var range='Kid';
                               return range;
                               break;

                        case  (age>=13 && age<= 19):
                               var range='Teenage';
                               return range;
                               break;

                        case  (age>=20 && age<= 40):
                               var range='Young Adult';
                               return range;
                               break;

                        case  (age>=41 && age<= 59):
                               var range='Adult';
                               return range;
                               break;
                        case  (age>=60 && age<= 100):
                               var range='Seniour Adult';
                               return range;
                               break;

                          default :      
                                var range='!!?';
                                return Range
                                break;
                   }

    }
    
    //Return an array            
    
    
    var ageAndRange = [age, calculateRange(age)];
    return ageAndRange; 
                   
                       
}

    
        var arr=[];
        arr=calcualteMyAge(myDob);

    alert('The age is '+arr[0]);
    alert('Range is '+arr[1]);
```

// ACCESSING THE RETURN VALUE FROM OUTSIDE FUNCTION

```
       var arr=[];
    arr=calcualteMyAge(myDob);

alert('The age is '+arr[0]);
alert('Range is '+arr[1]);
```

THIS IS giving un expected answers

```
Nan

 and 

function Range() {[native code]}
```

where it went wrong!?

Comment: OK. What your question? Is there a bug in your code? Is there something you don't understand? Are you familiar with ways of accessing JS arrays?

Comment: I was trying to access using   var a1[0]= calcualteMyAge(myDob);
    var a1[1]= calcualteMyAge(myDob);

Comment: please format your code and add more explanations

Comment: How to access age and range into 2 seperate variable outside the function

Comment: Try `var arr = calcualteMyAge(myDob); var element1 = arr[0]`.

Comment: The first major issue here is that you need to actually *call* your functions. For instance near the end, it's supposed to be `var ageAndRange = [age, calculateRange(age)];` You seem to wrap code you want to run into functions just for the sake of having functions, without understanding what they are or how to use them.

Comment: @Andy Quite honestly there's so much wrong here, closing it as *too broad* is probably better. The switch case debacle was just the most obvious sore thumb sticking out. Leaving this here then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696436/switch-case-in-jquery

Comment: thanks,I was doing some experiement,function inside a function and multiple return values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't capture elements from an array like you want.

Either do it the traditional way:

```
var arr = calcualteMyAge(myDob);
var age = arr[0];
var rang = arr[1];
```

Or with ES6 you can use destructuring:

```
const [ age, rang ] = calcualteMyAge(myDob);
```

Comment: var arr=calcualteMyAge(myDob);
prompt(arr[0]);
prompt(arr[1]);
added the code outside the fucntion

Comment: Try `alert` or `console.log` instead of `prompt`. It also might be an issue with the rest of your code as been pointed out in the comments. This answer is simply to show you how to access elements from a returned array, which was the question you asked.

Comment: Now it returning. alert shows 2 values !

Nan

 and also      

function Range() {[native code]}

Comment: please see the properly posted js script